# Chrome dev tools lose syntax highlighting for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, jsx, flowtype

I'm not sure if there if a way around this, or if maybe there is an issue when using mapped TypeScript files, but in many cases (larger files), I seem to lose the syntax highlighting.. [image]

As can be seen on the above image, it is ok until line 102, and from then on the rest of the file is just in red.

The above is from an Ionic 2 / Angular 2 project.

Appears to happen after the use of backtick string (but not always after the use of these)

It is not the end of the world, but the highlighting does make it easier to read. Anyone else experience this, and perhaps know a work around?

Comment: Known issue, not yet fixed, see https://crbug.com/659515

Comment: The issue affects JavaScript extension languages whenever angle brackets and template strings are in the same source file. Flow and TypeScript generics and JSX expression trigger it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

experiencing this problem all the time working with TS sourcemaps.
that's chromium engine trouble, there is also bug report about this problem
[(link to report)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=561301)
I gave up for this and using oldschool string concatenation.

Comment: Parent bug report is at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515